# Find an Inverse and a Square Root of a Linear operator as its polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space with $dim V = n$ and let $A \subset \mathcal L(V)$ (a linear map on $V$).

I have no idea how to find $T$ in $\mathcal P(A) \subset \mathcal L(V)$ (polynomials of $A$) such that $T = A^{-1}$, and $S$ in $\mathcal P(A) \subset \mathcal L(V)$ such that $S^2 = A$.

Is there supposed to be some "restrictions" on $A$ in order for such $T,S$ to exist?

------.-------(ok how can I add a line separator here...)

The original question defines $W_{n,\lambda} = \{ p(x)e^{\lambda x}| p(x)\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\}$, and a differentiation operator $D$ on it.

It asks to find $T$ and $S$ in $\mathcal P(D) \subset \mathcal L(W_{n,\lambda})$ such that $T = D^{-1}$ and $S^2 = D$.

My attempt was :

Since $(D - \lambda I)^{n+1} = 0$ then $(D- \lambda I)$ is nilpotent, and thus there's a basis ($v_{i} = x^{i}e^{\lambda x}$ for $i = 0, 1, ..., n$), with respect to which $D$ has a Jordan Form, i.e. $D = \lambda I + N$ where the $N$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix with unit super-diagonal entries(the diagonal right above the main diagonal), i.e. $N_{j,j+1} = 1$ and all zeros else where.

Based on this Jordan Form of $D$, I guess it's possible to obtain its Inverse $T$ (of course $\lambda \neq 0$ to guarantee its invertibility) and its Square Root $S$ (for $\lambda \geq 0$ maybe) through proper matrices computations, but then I'm stuck on how to transform such matrix results into polynomials of $D$.

Is there a way maybe to start directly manipulating some polynomials of $D$ to get $T$ and $S$?

--------Edited--------

Thanks for Gribouillis' help. Also I'd like to share what I found about [the Square Root of an operator](https://linear.axler.net/SquareRoots.pdf). It's the same formula.

Comment: For $T$ this is easy, simply take a polynomial that annihilates $A$ such as the minimal polynomial or the characteristic polynomial. For example if $A^3 - 2 A^2 + A - 7 I = 0$, then $A(A^2 - 2 A + I)/7 = I$ hence $A^{-1} = (A^2 - 2 A + I)/7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** for nilpotent matrices, one can use series such as
\begin{equation}
(I + N)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k N^k = I
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k}N^k\right)^2 = I + N
\end{equation}
because the sums only have a finite number of non-zero terms.